# Box API token request enterprise configuration issue

Tags: api, access-token, box-api, box

I am making a call to `https://api.box.com/oauth2/token` to get a token for a `user`.

I get a 400 with the following error:

```
Cannot obtain token based on the enterprise configuration for your app
```

I don't see this error message defined anywhere. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue here was that I was requesting a token for a non app user and my application was configured to allow access to app users only.

Comment: hmm do not understand what you mean

Comment: There are two kinds of Box users now that the developer edition is live: 1) app users and 2) normal Box users. The app users don't have a login and can be used only via API. Normal Box users have an email and password and a human can login via the UI. Depending on the configuration of the application, only certain types of users are allowed access via API.

Comment: do you know what configuration parameter that is in the Box admin / developer UI to configure that? i'm struggling to find it.