# What is the Box.com configuration setting to allow non-service accounts to use the api?

Tags: api, box

I have my box.com app set up with the following permissions:

*My security settings for application*

[image: setup]

*admin console -> business settings -> apps -> (under actions) -> click on ellipses of your app -> view app authorization*

[image: app auth]

Yet Right now, I get the error message described in this issue `"BoxOAuthException: {"error":"invalid_request","error_description":"Cannot obtain token based on the enterprise configuration for your app"}"` --> [Box API token request enterprise configuration issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33683246/box-api-token-request-enterprise-configuration-issue)

What is the Box.com configuration setting to allow non-service accounts to use the api?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your app, you can go to the section "User Access" and set it to "All Users"

[image]

All existing app authorizations now need to be reauthorized.

To do this... `admin console -> business settings -> apps -> (under actions) -> click on ellipses of your app -> view app authorization`

Notice in the below you might see "only app users can use app"

[image: app auth]

If so... Reauthorize the app `admin console -> business settings -> apps -> (under actions) -> click on ellipses of your app -> reauthorize`

It should now say "All users can connect."

[image]

Comment: did you authorize it?

Comment: i am able to get files, etc. and i can list groups. but i cannot list users.

Comment: how can I tell if i have properly set up authorization?

Comment: go to admin console -> enterprise settings -> apps -> (under actions) -> click on elipses of your app -> view app authorization.  If it doesn't have the right permissions, reauthorize it.

Comment: Business Settings you mean?

Comment: yes i am all set there. i updated the question with a screenshot.

Comment: Oh if you look closely you'll see a little "only app users of this app" checkbox in the app authorization. i need to reauth the app i think. when i hit re-authorize i get "all users can connect" now.